# Select values retrieve

Tags: php, javascript

Dear friends with this function I retrieve the values selected by my users and I put it in a hidden field to use it in my form:

```
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">  function updateHidden(sel){   
var f = document.contract;   
f.sel_value.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
 } </SCRIPT>
```

The problem is  that my select is inside a while cycle and therefore repeated. The js function set this way reads only the value selected in the first select.
I need to add a loop in the function, but I don’t know where to put it. 
This is my form:

```
    <form action="update.php" method="POST" name="contract">
 <table class="myp-table">
 <tr>
 <td class="head-act">Contract</td>
 </tr>
 <?php do { ?>
 <tr> 
 <td class="head-act"><select name="playerContract[]" onchange="updateHidden(this)">
 <option value="0" <?php if (!(strcmp(0, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>0</option>
  <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>1</option>
  <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>2</option>
   <option value="3" <?php if (!(strcmp(3, $row_datacontract['playerContract']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>3</option>
 </select>
<input type="hidden" name="sel_value"></td>
 <td><input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_datacontract['id']; ?>"/> </td>
 </tr>
 <?php } while ($row_datacontract = mysql_fetch_assoc($datacontract)); ?>
 <tr class="zebra">
 <td><input class="linkbuttonmp"  name="contract" id="submit" type="submit" value="Invio" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know you need a loop if you don't know where to put it?

Comment: I assume I need it but I don't know Js very well so I'm not really sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you will have `n` number of `<input type="hidden" name="sel_value">`, so how does it know which `name="sel_value"` to change? It would be best to change that to either `sel_value[]` or unique names.

But, your function can be changed easily using [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling)

```
function updateHidden(sel){   
  sel.nextElementSibling.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

see this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aFNdt/1/